# Error - Cannot start service Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, tcp

When I run `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` to build the project I get the error:

```
ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
```

If I change the port from 80 to 8300 for example:

```
   ports:
      - ${APP_PORT:-8300}:8300
    networks:
      - canvas
```

The command works but when I access the page "http://localhost:8300/" it appears "This site can’t be reached". I changed to port 8300 but not sure how this works if I can just change for any number that is not being used or if there are some specific numbers from which we can use?

Do you know how to properly correct the issue?

Comment: It sounds like you have two separate problems.  The "address is already in use" error means something else is using the `$APP_PORT` _on the host_; finding that is discussed in the linked question.  It also sounds like the process inside your container might not be listening on 0.0.0.0:8300.  The second `ports:` number must match what the process is actually listening on; you get your choice for the first port.

Comment: Thanks, so maybe its better to use the 80 right, however if I run lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN |grep :80 it shows 4 nginx entries.

Comment: If the process inside the container is listening on port 80, then the second number has to also be 80, but the first number can be anything that doesn't conflict.  Maybe you want something like `8300:80` to map host port 8300 to container port 80?